# Roslyn compiler does not see references

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, roslyn

I'm trying to create a .NET 6.0 app that will be able to compile another .NET 6.0 app. The problem is Roslyn does not seem to see references.

These are some of the errors I received from Roslyn:

> Invalid assembly name: The name contains invalid characters.
> Cannot find the name of the type or namespace 'List<>'
> Cannot find the name of the type or namespace 'Task'
> Cannot find the name of the type or namespace 'StreamReader'
> Name 'Environment' does not exist in the current context
> Name 'String' does not exist in the current context
> Name 'Array' does not exist in the current context
> Type 'MarshalByRefObject' is defined in an unreferenced assembly. You need to add a reference to the 'System.Runtime' assembly
> Type 'Uri' is defined in an unreferenced assembly. You need to add a reference to the 'System.Runtime' assembly

And this is my compiler code:

```
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

var references = new[]
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(dp, "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"))
};

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(output)
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.WindowsApplication))
    .AddReferences(references)
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

EmitResult emitResult = compilation.Emit(output);
```

I've already tried something like this:

```
var references = new[]
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(HttpClient).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Net.HttpWebRequest).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(List<>).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Task).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(StreamReader).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Environment).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MarshalByRefObject).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(dp, "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"))
};
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** create metadata references that way. Instead, use [Basic.Reference.Assemblies.Net60](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Basic.Reference.Assemblies.Net60) NuGet package. The [GitHub repo README](https://github.com/jaredpar/basic-reference-assemblies) has more instructions on how to use this package, but in short, all you need to do is `var references = ReferenceAssemblies.Net60` (and don't forget `using Basic.Reference.Assemblies;`).

Comment: Just did it like this `.AddReferences(Net60.References.All).AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(dp, "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll")`. But the errors are the same, there's still lack of namespaces etc.

Comment: Nevermid, i figured it out. The reason was lack of `using System.XXX` for the sublibraries such as `System.Net.Http`.